# Scala Sets contain the same elements, but sameElements() returns false

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Whilst working through the Scala [exercises on Iterables](http://scala-exercises.47deg.com/koans#iterables), I encountered the following strange behaviour:

```
val xs = Set(5,4,3,2,1)
val ys = Set(1,2,3,4,5)
xs sameElements ys       // true

val xs = Set(3,2,1)
val ys = Set(1,2,3)
xs sameElements ys       // false - WAT?!
```

Surely these Sets have the same elements, and should ignore ordering; and why does this work as expected only for the larger set?

Comment: Use `==` to test for equality irrespective of order and repetitions.

Comment: That's a good point for comparing `Set`s with one another, although I just noticed that `List(1,2,3) == Vector(1,2,3)` but `List(1,2,3) != Set(1,2,3)` and `List(1,2,3) != Array(1,2,3)` which is another potential minefield!

Comment: And as Paul Draper points out in the comments below, `Array(1,2,3) != Array(1,2,3)` !!

Answer (score 108, accepted):

The Scala collections library provides specialised implementations for Sets of fewer than 5 values (see the [source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.4/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Set.scala#L1)). The iterators for these implementations return elements *in the order in which they were added*, rather than the consistent, hash-based ordering used for larger Sets.

Furthermore, `sameElements` ([scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.Iterable@sameElements%28that:scala.collection.GenIterable%5BA%5D%29:Boolean)) is defined on `Iterable`s (it is implemented in `IterableLike` - see the [source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.5/src/library/scala/collection/IterableLike.scala#L1)); it returns true only if the iterators return the same elements in the same order.

So although `Set(1,2,3)` and `Set(3,2,1)` *ought* to be equivalent, their iterators are different, therefore `sameElements` returns false.

This behaviour is surprising, and arguably a bug since it violates the mathematical expectations for a Set (but only for certain sizes of Set!).

As I.K. points out in the comments, `==` works fine if you are just comparing Sets with one another, i.e. `Set(1,2,3) == Set(3,2,1)`. However, sameElements is more general in that it can compare the elements of any two iterables. For example, `List(1, 2, 3) == Array(1, 2, 3)` is false, but `List(1, 2, 3) sameElements Array(1, 2, 3)` is true.

More generally, equality can be confusing - note that:

```
List(1,2,3) == Vector(1,2,3)
List(1,2,3) != Set(1,2,3)
List(1,2,3) != Array(1,2,3)      
Array(1,2,3) != Array(1,2,3)
```

I have [submitted a fix](https://github.com/47deg/scala-exercises/issues/18) for the [Scala exercises](http://scala-exercises.47deg.com/koans#iterables) that explains the `sameElements` problem.

Comment: By the name of the method, I would expect it to disregard order regardless of the collection type. E.g. I would expect `List(1,2,3) sameElements List(3,2,1)` to evaluate to `true`, because both _contain the same elements_. If order matters, then what's the intended difference between `sameElements` and `==`?

Comment: Great find...In a big project something like this can drive anyone mad. Have you raised a ticket for this in the official scala issues.

Comment: I love scala so much but bugs like this are so disheartening.  Good find.

Comment: @Sarvesh_Kumar_Singh It's discussed [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-debate/je4vZbR3WbA) on the scala-debate list, but no ticket is mentioned there...

Comment: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-888 is closely related, but marked as Won't Fix (other than updating the documentation for sameElements)

Comment: @Zoltán, I completely agree. On difference: Scala does not override `==` for Arrays (or at least not anymore). So `==` and `sameElements` can produce different answers for arrays.

Comment: with Scala 2.13.0, IterableOnce defines sameElements as deprecated (in Iterable, AbstractIterable, AbstractSet, ImmutableKeySet, immutablle.Map, and others): "Use .iterator.sameElements instead"

Comment: "Use == to test for equality irrespective of order and repetitions" as M.K. stated above. Problem solved for Sets.