# DataFrame equality in Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, rdd

Assume `df1` and `df2` are two `DataFrame`s in Apache Spark, computed using two different mechanisms, e.g., Spark SQL vs. the Scala/Java/Python API.

Is there an idiomatic way to determine whether the two data frames are equivalent (equal, isomorphic), where equivalence is determined by the data (column names and column values for each row) being identical save for the ordering of rows & columns?

The motivation for the question is that there are often many ways to compute some big data result, each with its own trade-offs. As one explores these trade-offs, it is important to maintain correctness and hence the need to check for the equivalence/equality on a meaningful test data set.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are some standard ways in the Apache Spark test suites, however most of these involve collecting the data locally and if you want to do equality testing on large DataFrames then that is likely not a suitable solution.

Checking the schema first and then you could do an intersection to df3 and verify that the count of df1,df2 & df3 are all equal (however this only works if there aren't duplicate rows, if there are different duplicates rows this method could still return true).

Another option would be getting the underlying RDDs of both of the DataFrames, mapping to (Row, 1), doing a reduceByKey to count the number of each Row, and then cogrouping the two resulting RDDs and then do a regular aggregate and return false if any of the iterators are not equal.

Comment: Using the testing suite is an interesting idea. Collecting the data may be an option for small/medium data sets. What are the standard tools from there?

Comment: In the case of duplicate rows, how about appending an extra column of 'count' (of course by calculating functions.agg or by SQL) and then get the intersect as df3?

Comment: And how about taking a Union of both the datasets, then groupBy all the columns (of course using Sequence) and take count, and filter count%2. If it is > 0 then return false. Union is faster than intersection and will return an exception if columns are different (correct me, if I am wrong)

Comment: I don't think that will be any faster, the slow part of intersection is the shuffle which you'll also have with groupBy.

Answer (score 45):

**Scala (see below for PySpark)**

The [spark-fast-tests](https://github.com/MrPowers/spark-fast-tests) library has two methods for making DataFrame comparisons (I'm the creator of the library):

The `assertSmallDataFrameEquality` method collects DataFrames on the driver node and makes the comparison

```
def assertSmallDataFrameEquality(actualDF: DataFrame, expectedDF: DataFrame): Unit = {
  if (!actualDF.schema.equals(expectedDF.schema)) {
    throw new DataFrameSchemaMismatch(schemaMismatchMessage(actualDF, expectedDF))
  }
  if (!actualDF.collect().sameElements(expectedDF.collect())) {
    throw new DataFrameContentMismatch(contentMismatchMessage(actualDF, expectedDF))
  }
}
```

The `assertLargeDataFrameEquality` method compares DataFrames spread on multiple machines (the code is basically copied from [spark-testing-base](https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base))

```
def assertLargeDataFrameEquality(actualDF: DataFrame, expectedDF: DataFrame): Unit = {
  if (!actualDF.schema.equals(expectedDF.schema)) {
    throw new DataFrameSchemaMismatch(schemaMismatchMessage(actualDF, expectedDF))
  }
  try {
    actualDF.rdd.cache
    expectedDF.rdd.cache

    val actualCount = actualDF.rdd.count
    val expectedCount = expectedDF.rdd.count
    if (actualCount != expectedCount) {
      throw new DataFrameContentMismatch(countMismatchMessage(actualCount, expectedCount))
    }

    val expectedIndexValue = zipWithIndex(actualDF.rdd)
    val resultIndexValue = zipWithIndex(expectedDF.rdd)

    val unequalRDD = expectedIndexValue
      .join(resultIndexValue)
      .filter {
        case (idx, (r1, r2)) =>
          !(r1.equals(r2) || RowComparer.areRowsEqual(r1, r2, 0.0))
      }

    val maxUnequalRowsToShow = 10
    assertEmpty(unequalRDD.take(maxUnequalRowsToShow))

  } finally {
    actualDF.rdd.unpersist()
    expectedDF.rdd.unpersist()
  }
}
```

`assertSmallDataFrameEquality` is faster for small DataFrame comparisons and I've found it sufficient for my test suites.

**PySpark**

Here's a simple function that returns true if the DataFrames are equal:

```py
def are_dfs_equal(df1, df2):
    if df1.schema != df2.schema:
        return False
    if df1.collect() != df2.collect():
        return False
    return True
```

or simplified

```py
def are_dfs_equal(df1, df2): 
    return (df1.schema == df2.schema) and (df1.collect() == df2.collect())
```

You'll typically perform DataFrame equality comparisons in a test suite and will want a descriptive error message when the comparisons fail (a `True` / `False` return value doesn't help much when debugging).

Use the [chispa](https://github.com/MrPowers/chispa) library to access the `assert_df_equality` method that returns descriptive error messages for test suite workflows.

Comment: Looks like a nice library!

Comment: @Powers, do you know of any similar libraries for pySpark instead of Scala?

Comment: @jgtrz - I started building a PySpark version of spark-fast-tests called chispa: https://github.com/MrPowers/chispa. Need to finish it!

Comment: For those of us who stumbles here and implemented collect compare with `!actualDF.collect().sameElements(expectedDF.collect())` .  Please note that below post and be wary of ridiculousness of `sameElements()`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29008500/scala-sets-contain-the-same-elements-but-sameelements-returns-false/29008501#29008501

Comment: For the Pyspark folks: the function provided takes sorting into account. If you care only about contents repleace second condition with: `if df1.orderBy(*df1.columns).collect() !=df2.orderBy(*df2.columns).collect():`

Answer (score 16):

I don't know about idiomatic, but I think you can get a robust way to compare DataFrames as you describe as follows. (I'm using PySpark for illustration, but the approach carries across languages.)

```python
a = spark.range(5)
b = spark.range(5)

a_prime = a.groupBy(sorted(a.columns)).count()
b_prime = b.groupBy(sorted(b.columns)).count()

assert a_prime.subtract(b_prime).count() == b_prime.subtract(a_prime).count() == 0
```

This approach correctly handles cases where the DataFrames may have duplicate rows, rows in different orders, and/or columns in different orders.

For example:

```python
a = spark.createDataFrame([('nick', 30), ('bob', 40)], ['name', 'age'])
b = spark.createDataFrame([(40, 'bob'), (30, 'nick')], ['age', 'name'])
c = spark.createDataFrame([('nick', 30), ('bob', 40), ('nick', 30)], ['name', 'age'])

a_prime = a.groupBy(sorted(a.columns)).count()
b_prime = b.groupBy(sorted(b.columns)).count()
c_prime = c.groupBy(sorted(c.columns)).count()

assert a_prime.subtract(b_prime).count() == b_prime.subtract(a_prime).count() == 0
assert a_prime.subtract(c_prime).count() != 0
```

This approach is quite expensive, but most of the expense is unavoidable given the need to perform a full diff. And this should scale fine as it doesn't require collecting anything locally. If you relax the constraint that the comparison should account for duplicate rows, then you can drop the `groupBy()` and just do the `subtract()`, which would probably speed things up notably.

Comment: Just a note that this doesn't work with any unorderable data types such as maps, in which case you might have to drop those columns and do them separately.

Comment: I guess the count goes inside and agg() method, otherwise a_prime, b_prime and c_prime are numbers instead of dataframes

Comment: @dhalfageme - No, `.count()` on a `GroupedData` object -- which is what `.groupBy()` returns -- yields a DataFrame. Try it: `spark.range(3).groupBy('id').count().show()`

Answer (score 5):

Java:

```
assert resultDs.union(answerDs).distinct().count() == resultDs.intersect(answerDs).count();
```

Comment: Interesting solution, but I believe this does not handle duplicate rows correctly. For example (in Python): `a = spark.createDataFrame([(1,), (1,)], schema='id int'); b = spark.createDataFrame([(1,)], schema='id int'); assert a.union(b).distinct().count() == a.intersect(b).count();` The `assert` succeeds where it should instead fail.

Comment: try {
      return ds1.union(ds2)
              .groupBy(columns(ds1, ds1.columns()))
              .count()
              .filter("count % 2 > 0")
              .count()
          == 0;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return false;
    }

where columns method returns Seq<Columns> or Column[]

Answer (score 5):

Try doing the following:

```scala
df1.except(df2).isEmpty
```

Comment: That won't work in the case where `df2` is larger than `df1`. Perhaps if you make it symmetric by adding `&& df2.except(df1).isEmpty`...

Comment: even if you compare it each way it's still not correct since duplicate rows in df2 are matched by one row in df1 and vice versa.

Comment: Along with the above two comments, you also need to check for schema equality

Answer (score 5):

A scalable and easy way is to diff the two `DataFrame`s and count the non-matching rows:

```
df1.diff(df2).where($"diff" != "N").count
```

If that number is not zero, then the two `DataFrame`s are not equivalent.

The `diff` transformation is provided by [spark-extension](https://github.com/g-research/spark-extension).

It identifies **I**nserted, **C**hanged, **D**eleted and u**N**-changed rows.

Comment: Is this more scalable than the PySpark solution above using collect() ? Especially if you don't need a list of the differences?

Comment: If you mean the `df1.collect() != df2.collect()` PySpark solution, this is not scalable at all. Both DataFrames are loaded into the driver's memory. The above `diff` transormation scales with the cluster, meaning if your cluster can handle the DataFrames, it can handle the diff. So the answer then is: yes.

Answer (score 5):

There are 4 Options depending on whether you have **duplicate** rows or not.

Let's say we have two `DataFrame`s, z1 and z1. Option 1/2 are good for rows *without* duplicates. You can try these in `spark-shell`.

- Option 1: do except directly

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

def isEqual(left: DataFrame, right: DataFrame): Boolean = {
   if(left.columns.length != right.columns.length) return false // column lengths don't match
   if(left.count != right.count) return false // record count don't match
   return left.except(right).isEmpty && right.except(left).isEmpty
}
```

- Option 2: generate row hash by columns

```scala
def createHashColumn(df: DataFrame) : Column = {
   val colArr = df.columns
   md5(concat_ws("", (colArr.map(col(_))) : _*))
}

val z1SigDF = z1.select(col("index"), createHashColumn(z1).as("signature_z1"))
val z2SigDF = z2.select(col("index"), createHashColumn(z2).as("signature_z2"))
val joinDF = z1SigDF.join(z2SigDF, z1SigDF("index") === z2SigDF("index")).where($"signature_z1" =!= $"signature_z2").cache
// should be 0
joinDF.count
```

- Option 3: use `GroupBy`(for DataFrame with duplicate rows)

```scala
val z1Grouped = z1.groupBy(z1.columns.map(c => z1(c)).toSeq : _*).count().withColumnRenamed("count", "recordRepeatCount")
val z2Grouped = z2.groupBy(z2.columns.map(c => z2(c)).toSeq : _*).count().withColumnRenamed("count", "recordRepeatCount")

val inZ1NotInZ2 = z1Grouped.except(z2Grouped).toDF()
val inZ2NotInZ1 = z2Grouped.except(z1Grouped).toDF()
// both should be size 0
inZ1NotInZ2.show
inZ2NotInZ1.show
```

- Option 4, use `exceptAll`, which should also work for data with duplicate rows

```scala
// Source Code: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/50538600ec/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L2029
val inZ1NotInZ2 = z1.exceptAll(z2).toDF()
val inZ2NotInZ1 = z2.exceptAll(z1).toDF()
// same here, // both should be size 0
inZ1NotInZ2.show
inZ2NotInZ1.show
```

Comment: Re: option 2, `concat` does not work for all column types and `md5` can have collisions on big data.

Nice addition of Option 4 with `exceptAll`, which was only added in 2.4.0.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a little bit of deduplication in combination with a full outer join. The advantage of this approach is that it does not require you to collect results to the driver, and that it avoids running multiple jobs.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

// Generate some random data.
def random(n: Int, s: Long) = {
  spark.range(n).select(
    (rand(s) * 10000).cast("int").as("a"),
    (rand(s + 5) * 1000).cast("int").as("b"))
}
val df1 = random(10000000, 34)
val df2 = random(10000000, 17)

// Move all the keys into a struct (to make handling nulls easy), deduplicate the given dataset
// and count the rows per key.
def dedup(df: Dataset[Row]): Dataset[Row] = {
  df.select(struct(df.columns.map(col): _*).as("key"))
    .groupBy($"key")
    .agg(count(lit(1)).as("row_count"))
}

// Deduplicate the inputs and join them using a full outer join. The result can contain
// the following things:
// 1. Both keys are not null (and thus equal), and the row counts are the same. The dataset
//    is the same for the given key.
// 2. Both keys are not null (and thus equal), and the row counts are not the same. The dataset
//    contains the same keys.
// 3. Only the right key is not null.
// 4. Only the left key is not null.
val joined = dedup(df1).as("l").join(dedup(df2).as("r"), $"l.key" === $"r.key", "full")

// Summarize the differences.
val summary = joined.select(
  count(when($"l.key".isNotNull && $"r.key".isNotNull && $"r.row_count" === $"l.row_count", 1)).as("left_right_same_rc"),
  count(when($"l.key".isNotNull && $"r.key".isNotNull && $"r.row_count" =!= $"l.row_count", 1)).as("left_right_different_rc"),
  count(when($"l.key".isNotNull && $"r.key".isNull, 1)).as("left_only"),
  count(when($"l.key".isNull && $"r.key".isNotNull, 1)).as("right_only"))
summary.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
  return ds1.union(ds2)
          .groupBy(columns(ds1, ds1.columns()))
          .count()
          .filter("count % 2 > 0")
          .count()
      == 0;
} catch (Exception e) {
  return false;
}

Column[] columns(Dataset<Row> ds, String... columnNames) {
List<Column> l = new ArrayList<>();
for (String cn : columnNames) {
  l.add(ds.col(cn));
}
return l.stream().toArray(Column[]::new);}
```

columns method is supplementary and can be replaced by any method that returns Seq

Logic:

1. Union both the datasets, if columns are not matching, it will throw an exception and hence return false.
2. If columns are matching then groupBy on all columns and add a column count. Now, all the rows have count in the multiple of 2 (even for duplicate rows).
3. Check if there is any row that has count not divisible by 2, those are the extra rows.

Comment: Can someone confirm if this union solution has a better performance compared to joins solutions provided above? (and also it works with duplicate rows)

Comment: This unfortunately is not correct, if one of the datasets has a distinct row repeated twice you'll have a false positive.