# Spark - compare 2 dataframes without using hardcoded column names

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
I need to create a way to compare 2 data frames and do not use any hardcoded data, so that I can upload at any time 2 files and compare them without changing anything.

df1
+--------------------+--------+----------------+----------+
|                  ID|colA.   |colB.           |colC      |
+--------------------+--------+----------------+----------+
|(122C8984ABF9F6EF...|       0|              10|     APPLE|
|(122C8984ABF9F6EF...|       0|              20|     APPLE|
|(122C8984ABF9F6EF...|       0|              10|    GOOGLE|
|(122C8984ABF9F6EF...|       0|              10|     APPLE|
|(122C8984ABF9F6EF...|       0|              15|   SAMSUNG|
|(122C8984ABF9F6EF...|       0|              10|     APPLE|
+--------------------+--------+----------------+----------+


df2
+--------------------+--------+----------------+----------+
|                  ID|colA.   |colB            |colC      |
+--------------------+--------+----------------+----------+
|(122C8984ABF9F6EF...|       0|              10|     APPLE|
|(122C8984ABF9F6EF...|       0|              20|     APPLE|
|(122C8984ABF9F6EF...|       0|              10|     APPLE|
|(122C8984ABF9F6EF...|       0|              30|     APPLE|
|(122C8984ABF9F6EF...|       0|              15|   SAMSUNG|
|(122C8984ABF9F6EF...|       0|              15|    GOOGLE|
+--------------------+--------+----------------+----------+
```

I need to compare these 2 data frames and count the differences from each column.
My output should look like this:|

```
+--------------+-------------+-----------------+------------+------+
|Attribute Name|Total Records|Number Miss Match|% Miss Match|Status|
+--------------+-------------+-----------------+------------+------+
|      colA|            6|                0|       0.0 %|  Pass|
colB.       |           6|                3|        50 %|  Fail|
|    colC. |            6|                2|      33.3 %|  Fail||
+--------------+-------------+-----------------+------------+------+
```

I know how to compare the columns when using hardcoded column names , by my requirement is to compare it dynamically.
What I did so far was to select a column from each data frame, but this doesn't seem the right way to do it.

```
 val columnsAll = df1.columns.map(m=>col(m))
 val df1_col1 = df1.select(df1.columns.slice(1,2).map(m=>col(m)):_*).as("Col1")
 val df2_col1 = df2.select(df2.columns.slice(1,2).map(m=>col(m)):_*).as("Col2")
```

Comment: Total number of records is what when you have 2 dataframes?

Comment: Total Records is the number that is in common from both dataframes, in this case is 8. I compared both dataframes in number of rows, as "inner" and the total is 8. Now I need to compare each column and if there are differences, tio count them and I don't know how to compare the columns without using their names.

Comment: Well is therea positional depency, the key to be compared?

Comment: The only column name that can be used is the ID column.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways here:

1. The [spark-fast-tests](https://github.com/MrPowers/spark-fast-tests) library has two methods for making DataFrame comparisons:

The `assertSmallDataFrameEquality` method collects DataFrames on the driver node and makes the comparison

```
def assertSmallDataFrameEquality(actualDF: DataFrame, expectedDF: DataFrame): Unit = {
  if (!actualDF.schema.equals(expectedDF.schema)) {
    throw new DataFrameSchemaMismatch(schemaMismatchMessage(actualDF, expectedDF))
  }
  if (!actualDF.collect().sameElements(expectedDF.collect())) {
    throw new DataFrameContentMismatch(contentMismatchMessage(actualDF, expectedDF))
  }
}
```

2. Using `df2.except(df1)`

For details of these 2 ways, you can refer [DataFrame equality in Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31197353/dataframe-equality-in-apache-spark)
[Compare two Spark dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45553300/compare-two-spark-dataframes/45562949)

Comment: Thank you, that's a good starting point.