# How to compare 2 datasets in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataset, scalatest

I am creating unit tests for a Scala application using Scala Test. I have the actual and expected results as Dataset . When I verified manually both the data and schema matches between actual and expected datasets.

```
Actual Dataset= actual_ds
Expected Dataset = expected_ds
```

when I execute below command ,it returns False.

```
assert(actual_ds.equals(expected_ds))
```

Could anyone suggest what could be the reason. And is there any other inbuilt function to compare the datasets in scala?

Answer (score 2):

That `.equals()` is from Java Object `.equals` so it's correct that the assert fails.

I would start testing two datasets with:

1. `assert actual_ds.schema == expected_ds.schema`
2. `assert actual_ds.count() == expected_ds.count()`

And then checking this question: [DataFrame equality in Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31197353/dataframe-equality-in-apache-spark)

Answer (score 1):

Use one of libraries designed for spark tests, [spark-fast-tests](https://github.com/MrPowers/spark-fast-tests) , [spark-testing-base](https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base), [spark-test](https://github.com/univalence/spark-tools/tree/master/spark-test)

They are quite ease to use and with their help its easy to compare two datasets with formatted message on output

You may start with spark-fast-tests (you can find usage in readme file) and check others if it does not suite your needs (fro example if you need other output formatting)