# Scala - Collection comparison - Why is Set(1) == ListSet(1)?

Tags: scala, collections, comparison

Why is the output of this comparison outputs `true`?

```
import scala.collection.immutable.ListSet

Set(1) == ListSet(1) // Expect false

//Output
res0: Boolean = true
```

And in a more general sense, how the comparison is actually done?

Comment: It's worth nothing that the implementation boils down to `set1.forall(set2.contains)` (after a size check, etc.), which means that if you're comparing large sets and care about performance, the `ListSet` should come first.

Comment: …for example `(0 to 100000).to[Set] == (0 to 100000).to[ListSet]` takes ~14 seconds on my laptop, while the reverse is instantaneous.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the inheritance chain `Set <: GenSet <: GenSetLike` is a bit lengthy, it might be not immediately obvious where to look for the code of `equals`, so I thought maybe I quote it here:

[GenSetLike.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.3/src/library/scala/collection/GenSetLike.scala#L115):

```
  /** Compares this set with another object for equality.
   *
   *  '''Note:''' This operation contains an unchecked cast: if `that`
   *        is a set, it will assume with an unchecked cast
   *        that it has the same element type as this set.
   *        Any subsequent ClassCastException is treated as a `false` result.
   *  @param that the other object
   *  @return     `true` if `that` is a set which contains the same elements
   *              as this set.
   */
  override def equals(that: Any): Boolean = that match {
    case that: GenSet[_] =>
      (this eq that) ||
      (that canEqual this) &&
      (this.size == that.size) &&
      (try this subsetOf that.asInstanceOf[GenSet[A]]
       catch { case ex: ClassCastException => false })
    case _ =>
      false
  }
```

Essentially, it checks whether the other object is also a `GenSet`, and if yes, it attempts to perform some fail-fast checks (like comparing `size` and invoking `canEqual`), and if the sizes are equal, it checks whether this set is a subset of another set, presumably by checking each element.

So, the exact class used to represent the set at runtime is irrelevant, what matters is that the compared object is also a `GenSet` and has the same elements.

Answer (score 4):

From [Scala collections equality](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/equality.html):

> The collection libraries have a uniform approach to equality and hashing. The idea is, first, to divide collections into sets, maps, and sequences.
>
> ...
>
> On the other hand, within the same category, collections are equal if and only if they have the same elements

In your case, both collections are considered sets and they contain the same elements, hence, they're equal.

Comment: This is correct, but just one note of caution for sequences: `List(1, 2, 3) == Vector(1, 2, 3)` but `List(1, 2, 3) != Array(1, 2, 3)` and `Array(1, 2, 3) != Array(1, 2, 3)` - see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29008500/scala-sets-contain-the-same-elements-but-sameelements-returns-false/29008501#29008501

Comment: `Array` is not part of the `collections` package, there's more info [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/arrays.html) about the peculiarities of `Array`. If cast to a `Seq[Int]` ( which would wrap it as a `WrappedArray`), then it'll be equal to an equivalent `List`

Answer (score 3):

[Scala 2.12.8 documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/ListSet.html):

> This class implements immutable sets using a list-based data
>   structure.

So ListSet is a set too but with concrete (list-based) implementation.